# Check if host is reachable on specific network interface

Tags: go

I know that I can use `net.DialTimeout` to check if host is reachable. But using that approach I can’t specify interface or get back what interface the host was reached on, as far as I know.

I’m looking for the functionality of pings -I flag, like

```
ping -I eth0 www.google.se
```

but would prefer not to resort to `exec.Command` to keep platform compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `interfaceByName` method as mentioned [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#InterfaceByName). Example:

```
func main() {
    eth0, err := net.InterfaceByName("eth0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    adds, err := eth0.Addrs()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    tcpAddr := &net.TCPAddr{
        IP: adds[0].(*net.IPNet).IP,
    }

    d := net.Dialer{LocalAddr: tcpAddr, Timeout: time.Second * 60}

    _, err = d.Dial("tcp", "www.google.se")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```